# regex - string match wrong output

Tags: java, regex

My String is :

```
04/30/13 INCOME REINVEST 0.0245 $24.66 $12.34 1.998 1,008.369 05/31/13 INCOME REINVEST 0.0228 $22.99 $12.22 1.881 1,010.250 06/28/13 INCOME REINVEST 0.0224 $22.63 $11.97 1.891 1,012.141
```

my regex is :

```
([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})\\s*([\\w ]+).+?\\$((?:(?:\\d+|\\d+,\\d+)\\.\\d+\\s\\$?){3})
```

My expected output is from the 3 groups :

```
04/30/13 INCOME REINVEST 24.66 $12.34 1.998
```

for the first match. But I get :

```
04/30/13 INCOME REINVEST 0 24.66 $12.34 1.998
```

Why do I get an extra `0` in the 2nd group matched?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `\w` matches word characters and digits are word characters, thus `[\w ]+` will match `INCOME REINVEST 0`. It stops at the dot since a dot is not a word character (`\w` is defined as a shortcut for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`).

You'd need use another class, e.g. `[a-zA-Z_ ]` instead of `[\w ]`. (For more flexibility you could also use this: `[\p{L}\s]` which means "any letter or whitespace")

Answer (score 0):

How about `split()`?

```
String s = "04/30/13 INCOME REINVEST 0.0245 $24.66 $12.34 1.998 1,008.369 05/31/13 INCOME REINVEST 0.0228 $22.99 $12.22 1.881 1,010.250 06/28/13 INCOME REINVEST 0.0224 $22.63 $11.97 1.891 1,012.141";

String[] words = s.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(words[0]); // 04/30/13
System.out.println(words[1]); // INCOME
System.out.println(words[2]); // REINVEST
System.out.println(words[4]); // $24.66
System.out.println(words[5]); // $12.34
System.out.println(words[6]); // 1.998
```